# Including facebook.php in a wordpress page template?

Tags: page-template, facebook

I was wondering if I can include Facebook's php sdk file into a wordpress page template ?

For example in page.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        <!--BEGIN: wrapper-->
        <div class="wrapper">    
        <!--BEGIN: scrol left-->
        <div class="ppading">
            <div class="scroll-pane">

                      <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php the_content(); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>


            </div>
        </div><!--END: scrol left-->
        </div><!-- END: wrapper -->    
        <!--BEGIN: shadow-->
        <div id="shadow"></div>
        <!--END: shadow-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Can i attempt to include facebook.php like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>


    <?php


    session_start();
    echo "pass sds1";
    require_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/include/facebook.php';
    echo "pass";
    $config = array(
        "appId" => "XXXX",
        "secret" => "XXXX");

    $fb = new Facebook($config);
    echo $fb;
    $user = $fb->getUser();
    echo $user;
    ?>



        <!--BEGIN: wrapper-->
        <div class="wrapper">    
        <!--BEGIN: scrol left-->
        <div class="ppading">
            <div class="scroll-pane">

                      <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php the_content(); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>


            </div>
        </div><!--END: scrol left-->
        </div><!-- END: wrapper -->    
        <!--BEGIN: shadow-->
        <div id="shadow"></div>
        <!--END: shadow-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've tried doing the above, but the `echo "pass";` was not executed, 
this means that the `require_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/include/facebook.php';` line has failed.

Can anyone advise me on how to achieve this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
require_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/include/facebook.php';
```

...with this:

```
get_template_part( '/include/facebook.php' );
```

And if that doesn't work, try this:

```
locate_template( 'include/facebook.php', true );
```

Comment: hey good day and thanks for your reply. The facebook.php appears to be loaded. However, I dont see any thing printed out from $fb. It seems that the line  $fb = new Facebook($config); is failing ( my app id and secret are correct as the same code is tested as a standalone script. Any ideas how to make the $fb = new Facebook($config);
    echo $fb; work ?  thanks!

Comment: That would probably be a separate question...